# Jquery - find the cost based on checking two arrays multiplied by a static number

Tags: javascript, jquery

My first post so I hope I do this right and sorry I am still learning so not sure if I even post this correctly.  What I kinda sort of did was pseudo code code what I need but the execution is way off.
So my variables are books, program, and courses.

To find my book cost I need to check to see what group the program falls in (arrays) then multiply it by the number of courses that are being taken.

```
var programGroup1=["Arts", "Crafts", "Painting"];
var programGroup2=["Zumba", "Ballet", "Jazz"];
var programGroup3=["Math", "Science", "History"];
var books

if(programGroup1){
  books = course * 10
}else if(programGroup2){
  books = course * 20
}else if(programGroup3){
  books = course * 30
}else{
  end();
}

<select id="program" name="program" >
<option value="" selected="true">--</option>
<option value="Arts" >Arts</option>
<option value="Crafts" >Crafts</option>
<option value="Painting" >Painting</option>
<option value="Zumba" >Zumba</option>
<option value="Ballet" >Ballet</option>
<option value="Jazz" >Jazz</option>
<option value="Math" >Math</option>
<option value="Science" >Science</option>
<option value="History" >History</option>
</select>
<select id="course" name="course">
<option value="" selected="true">--</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

So then if you took Arts and course 5 your books would be 10 * 5 and it would output $50, or if you took crafts and course 5 it would be 20 * 5 and would output $100.

Thanks for any help I am really trying to learn just need some help.

Comment: `var program2=["Crafts", "Crafts2"], "Crafts3"]];` has two extra `]`

Comment: Thanks just fixed that, was bad typing on my part

Comment: I think the example I provided gave a false sense of the data I needed.  The options won't all be similar arts, arts2, arts3 I just did that for simplicity.  The reason why in my pseudo code I was attempting to use a case was because I was trying to group similar programs.  Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
// If a select changes
$('select').change(function () {
  var psel, csel, program, course, total;

  // Get the values of both selectors
  psel = $('#Program').find('option:selected').val();
  csel = $('#course').find('option:selected').val();

  // Assign the program var a value depending on the program type
  if (psel.indexOf('Arts') > -1) { program = 10; }
  if (psel.indexOf('Crafts') > -1) { program = 20; }

  // Set the value of course to the value of the selected option
  course = csel;

  // Add them together
  total = program * course;

  // And only if they all exists (if both selections have been done), alert the total
  if (program && course && total) {
    alert('Total ' + total);
  }
});
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2LQT/22/).

Comment: I had to update my example I don't think I was being clear enough, your answer is close to what I am trying to do but the values will be random so I need to be able to check against an array to determine what group they are in.

Answer (score 0):

You are best off doing something like this:

- For each program, set an action and value, like this: `$('option[value="Arts"]').data({ action:'*', value: 10 });`
- When one of the `select`s changes, get the value and action, and apply them to the cost.

Sample HTML:

```
<select id="program" name="program" >
    <option value="" selected="true">--</option>
    <option value="Arts" >Arts</option>
    <option value="Arts2" >Art2s</option>
    <option value="Arts3" >Arts3</option>
    <option value="Crafts" >Crafts</option>
    <option value="Crafts2" >Crafts2</option>
    <option value="Crafts3" >Crafts3</option>
</select>
<select id="course" name="course">
    <option value="0" selected="true">--</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Sample JS using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#program option[value=""]').data({ action:'*', value: 0 });
    $('option[value="Arts"]').data({ action:'*', value: 10 });
    $('option[value="Arts2"]').data({ action:'*', value: 20 });
    $('option[value="Arts3"]').data({ action:'*', value: 30 });
    console.log($('option[value=Arts]').data());

    $('select').on('change', function() {
        var cost = parseFloat($('#course').val());
        var program = $('#program').val();
        var program_obj = $('#program option[value="'+program+'"');
        var action = program_obj.data('action');
        var arts_val = parseFloat(program_obj.data('value'));
        switch(action) {
            case '*':
                cost = cost * arts_val;
                break;
            case '/':
                cost = cost / arts_val;
                break;
            case '+':
                cost = cost + arts_val;
                break;
            case '-':
                cost = cost - arts_val;
                break;

        }
        alert(cost);

    });
});
```

[Here's a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/sc2ES/2/)

Comment: One small thing I don't think the alert is working on the fiddle changing the drop downs has no effect.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are having problems with it; it works fine for me.  Maybe `alert()` was being blocked? Try this tweaked version: http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/sc2ES/2/

Comment: It works in Chrome but not in my version of Firefox.  Your solution I think is close but my example was to literal and so I can't use what you put together.  Sorry I updated my example, basically I need to be able to check when a select is made what group it is in as that will determine the book cost times the number of courses.  Sorry.